# How to walk along UTF-16 codepoints?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-16

I have the following definition of varying ranges which correspond to codepoints and surrogate pairs:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Description

My code is based on `ConvertUTF.c` from the [Clang implementation](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/ConvertUTF_8c_source.html).

I'm currently struggling with wrapping my head around how to do this.

The code which is most relevant from LLVM's implementation that I'm trying to understand is:

```
unsigned short bytesToWrite = 0;
const u32char_t byteMask = 0xBF;
const u32char_t byteMark = 0x80; 
u8char_t* target = *targetStart;

utf_result result = kConversionOk;
const u16char_t* source = *sourceStart;
while (source < sourceEnd) {
   u32char_t ch;
   const u16char_t* oldSource = source; /* In case we have to back up because of target overflow. */
   ch = *source++;
   /* If we have a surrogate pair, convert to UTF32 first. */
   if (ch >= UNI_SUR_HIGH_START && ch <= UNI_SUR_HIGH_END) {
      /* If the 16 bits following the high surrogate are in the source buffer... */
      if (source < sourceEnd) {
         u32char_t ch2 = *source;
         /* If it's a low surrogate, convert to UTF32. */
         if (ch2 >= UNI_SUR_LOW_START && ch2 <= UNI_SUR_LOW_END) {
            ch = ((ch - UNI_SUR_HIGH_START) << halfShift)
               + (ch2 - UNI_SUR_LOW_START) + halfBase;
            ++source;
         } else if (flags == kStrictConversion) { /* it's an unpaired high surrogate */
            --source; /* return to the illegal value itself */
            result = kSourceIllegal;
            break;
         }
      } else { /* We don't have the 16 bits following the high surrogate. */
         --source; /* return to the high surrogate */
         result = kSourceExhausted;
         break;
      }
   } else if (flags == kStrictConversion) {
      /* UTF-16 surrogate values are illegal in UTF-32 */
      if (ch >= UNI_SUR_LOW_START && ch <= UNI_SUR_LOW_END) {
         --source; /* return to the illegal value itself */
         result = kSourceIllegal;
         break;
      }
   }
   ...
```

Specifically they say in the comments:

> If we have a surrogate pair, convert to UTF32 first.

and then:

> If it's a low surrogate, convert to UTF32.

I'm getting lost along the lines of "if we have.." and "if it's.." and my response being while reading the comments: "what do we have?" and "what is it?"

I believe `ch` and `ch2` is the first char16 and the next char16 (if one exists), checking to see if the second is part of a surrogate pair, and then walking along each char16 (or do you walk along pairs of chars?) until the end.

I'm getting lost along the lines of how they are using `UNI_SUR_HIGH_START`, `UNI_SUR_HIGH_END`, `UNI_SUR_LOW_START`, `UNI_SUR_LOW_END`, and their use of `halfShift` and `halfBase`.

Wikipedia also notes:

> There was an attempt to rename "high" and "low" surrogates to "leading" and "trailing" due to their numerical values not matching their names. This appears to have been abandoned in recent Unicode standards.

Making note of "leading" and "trailing" in any responses may help clarify things as well.

Comment: Have you read the [Unicode FAQ on reading surrogate pairs](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-3)?

Answer (score 2):

`ch >= UNI_SUR_HIGH_START && ch <= UNI_SUR_HIGH_END` checks if `ch` is in the range where high surrogates are, that is, [D800-DBFF]. That's it. Then the same is done for checking if `ch2` is in the range where low surrogates are, meaning [DC00-DFFF].

`halfShift` and `halfBase` are just used as prescribed by the UTF-16 decoding algorithm, which turns a pair of surrogates into the scalar value they represent. There's nothing special being done here; it's the textbook implementation of that algorithm, without any tricks.